# DocuSign: Cannot prefill multiple text tabs with the same label using Composite Template XML

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to prefill the text tab in XML but only the first document got prefilled, I have tried the "\\*" logic too but was unable to get the all the documents prefilled. Below is the XML which I am sending as a request while generating the Composite XML.

I have used without using "\\*" and even used it once in first template section but still not able to get the prefilled data.

I am using visual studio 2013 on which I have to write 4 backslashes with * while debugging it generates the below XML.

In the below mentioned XML the are more then one templates with same signers and with same label fields, the label are generated dynamically which may or may not be contained in the whole envelope for e.g. some document may contains first name and last name and some may contain the city name, state ,etc. What I want is whatever the labels are that should be prefilled in docusign, but only the first document got prefilled. I have generated the composite Template XML for all the labels that could possibly come in my envelope. I am fetching the document list dynamically.

Below is the XML:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<accountId>ACCOUNTID</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <compositeTemplates>
     <compositeTemplate>
       <serverTemplates>
         <serverTemplate>
           <sequence>1</sequence>
<templateId>TemplateId1</templateId>
         </serverTemplate>
       </serverTemplates>
       <inlineTemplates>
         <inlineTemplate>
           <sequence>1</sequence>
           <recipients>
             <signers>
               <signer>
                 <email>xxxxx@gmail.com </email>
                 <name>234 234</name>
                 <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                 <roleName>Contractor</roleName>
                 <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                 <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                 <tabs>
                   <textTabs>
                     <text>
<tabLabel>\\*lblFullName</tabLabel>
                       <value>234 234</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
<tabLabel>\\*lblFirstName</tabLabel>
                       <value>234</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
<tabLabel>\\*lblLastName</tabLabel>
                       <value>234</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblEmail</tabLabel>
<value>jogendertaneja@gmail.com</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblPhone</tabLabel>
                       <value>1231231231</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblPhone1</tabLabel>
                       <value>123</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblPhone2</tabLabel>
                       <value>123</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblPhone3</tabLabel>
                       <value>1231</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
<tabLabel>\\*lblCityStateZip</tabLabel>
                       <value>123,MI,12312</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblAddress</tabLabel>
                       <value>123</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblCity</tabLabel>
                       <value>123</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblState</tabLabel>
                       <value>MI</value>
                     </text>
                     <text>
                       <tabLabel>\\*lblZip</tabLabel>
                       <value>12312</value>
                     </text>
                   </textTabs>
                 </tabs>
               </signer>
             </signers>
           </recipients>
         </inlineTemplate>
       </inlineTemplates>
     </compositeTemplate>
...
...
</compositeTemplates>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: I believe you want to update your account setting for Data Population Scope to be "Envelope". http://community.docusign.com/t5/Miscellaneous/Data-population-scope-setting/td-p/28918

Comment: I have set the Data Population Scope to be "Envelope", but it still not working, Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply the same value to multiple tabs with the same name across documents, set the data population scope to **Envelope** instead of **Document**.

This can be found on the DocuSign Web App’s Preference Area under **Features**. If you do not see it on your account, make a request with DocuSign Support to have the option visible for your account.

Comment: I have set the Data Population Scope to be "Envelope", but it still not working, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that all tabs in envelope is not getting prefilled because of presence of pageNumber. Can you please try by removing 1 and see if it works.